# How to get Firestore Data by method in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get users name but Flutter gives this error:

```
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
```

Method:

```
  String getUserNameFromUID(String uid) {

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        return doc["name"];
      });

    });

  }
```

How can I solve my problem? if I add return 0 to end of the method it always gives 0.

It always gives 0.(I do not want 0, I want get user name from uid)

```
  String getUserNameFromUID(String uid) {

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        return doc["name"];
      });

    });

return "0";

  }
```

**EDIT:** I need a String solution, not Future. The method should return String...

Because my UI is not future builder. Isn't there any way to return one data as String in Firestore database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your function should return a `Future<String>` since it relies on firestore's `get` wich also returns a future. Also `docs` is a list, you have to return just one. The first one i guess. In the UI just use a `FutureBuilder`

```
 Future<String> getUserNameFromUID(String uid) async {

    final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
        .get();
     return snapshot.docs.first['name'];

  }
```

Since you can't use `FutureBuilder`. An ugly alternative is to pass a callback to `getUserNameFromUID` and call `setState` from there.

```
void getUserNameFromUID(String uid, Function (String name) onData) {

    final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
        .get().then((s) => onData(s.docs.first['name']));
  }
```

On your UI

```
...
getUserNameFromUID(uid, (String name){
  setState(()=> name = name);
});
```

From your last comment just inherit from `StatefulWidget`. And call the function from inside.

```
@override
void initState() {
   getUserNameFromUID(uid);
}
```

If you had special requirements about not being able to modify the UI, you should mention that as it conditions the way to use the backend services.

Comment: My UI is not future builder so is there any way to get user name rather future builder?

Comment: I need to return String, not Future.. is there any way to return only string?

Comment: @gurkanstack No. You need to modify your UI, or use an alternative like bloc. And then emit an event from your function and react to a state change. Always remember that if an API as in firebase returns a `Future` you need to return a `Future` of something in the caller function if you need it to return.

Comment: Hello @gurkanstack, does it answer your question? Please consider accepting the answer. Thanks

Comment: No, I need a solution without Future if it possible..

Comment: There's no reason you can't return a Future just because you're not using a FutureBuilder. Just call setState, updating a variable with the String result from the Future.

Comment: How can I implement setState? I just want to  get only one string data from firebase. I think it should not be hard because my demand is very clear & sensible. I need a function to return a String value from Firebase(stop all other tasks, then call this function in my UI without Future Builder, because my structure is not future builder)

Comment: How can I use it in children text? My text is like this: 
children: <Widget>[ Text(
                        getUserNameFromUID(id),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: ...,
                        style: ...,
                      ), ],

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved by problem by making my UI future builder.. You can remove last part of your answer..